# ParseInput changes the out Tokens based on the comments in the script

Tags: powershell, parsing, tokenize

I want to use ParseInput method from Language.Parser class to get all the tokens from a script.
The problem is as long as I don't have any comments in the script it works fine but when I add a comment is stops parsing further. Actually it gives me the whole comment and all the lines following the comments as the last token.
If you test the code you see the i is changing based on the place you put a comment in a script.
I have used a test code placed in test.ps1, tested with different codes still behaving the same.

```
$ParsedScriptContent = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput((Get-Content .\test.ps1), [ref]$ParserTokens, [ref]$null)

$i = 0

$ParserTokens | foreach{

    if($_){

        $i++
    }
}

Write-Host $i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
System.Management.Automation.PSParser]::Tokenize((Get-Content C:\Script.ps1),[ref]$null) | %{$_}
```

for your Powershell Tokenize

If you want to use **[System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]** and pull from a file based script change **ParseInput** to **ParseFile**

```
$ParsedScriptContent = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile("C:\Test.ps1", [ref]$ParserTokens, [ref]$null)
$ParserTokens | ForEach-Object{$_}
```

If using **ParseInput** then you should pull inline like

```
$script=@'
$a = 1;$b = 2
#hello
$c = $a + $b;$c
'@
$ParserTokens = $null
$ParsedScriptContent = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($script, [ref]$ParserTokens, [ref]$null)
$ParserTokens | ForEach-Object{$_}
```

Comment: Thanks! I decided to use both methods to analyze the script. The Tokenize returns PSToken while ParseFile returns Token. Theoretically both should have the same properties but it's different.